# Using a word tautology

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Per Google "tautology" is an expression or phrase that says the same thing twice, just in a different way.

Can it be applied to a public discussion of proposed project that lasts several month where each discussion exposes a different angle but as a whole is becoming repetitive.

Comment: No, that is "repetitive" as you say, or "covering the same ground." An example of tautology is "I forgot my PIN number."

Comment: *beating a dead horse* might be idiomatic here.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I still don't understand "I forgot my PIN number."

Comment: When the acronym **PIN** is expanded, the sentence says "I forgot my personal identification number number."

Comment: I got it, thank you! Many say PIN code which is redundant. Or Chai Tea, where Chai means Tea.

Comment: Pin code is  correct. PIN number is tautology.

Answer (score 1):

As weather r  Vane rightly pointed  out   **tautology**
  does not fit in your context.

In the context you talked about  the discussions are becoming repetitive. I think  they  are  **beating  about the  bush**

Tautology  is a way of talking in which some words are unnecessarily repeated.

Example:

> **Your acting is  completely  devoid  of   emotion.**

In the sentence above   _completely _ is unnecessary  because  devoid  means   **completely  empty**

The correct  sentence is  given below:

> **Your acting  is   devoid  of   emotion**

Similarly  some nonnative  speakers   say:

> **We  discussed  about  politics**

Here   **about**  is unnecessary.

Here is  a link which  helps  you know  about  tautology  in English.

https://literarydevices.net/tautology/

Comment: So it basically means redundant?  Like in close proximity? Good link, thank you